# Jenkins building angular project gets Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins

So the project consists of angular front-end and spring boot back-end. When building pipeline project in Jenkins it fails while building the front side. I believe the error is due to different versions of node, angular etc? But I can't seem to find fix to this problem. There's some warning but only one error about the property 'resolve' being undefined.

```
14:49:45 [INFO] npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@5.3.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
14:49:45 [INFO] npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@5.3.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
14:49:45 [INFO] npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@5.3.1 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
14:49:45 [INFO] npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
14:49:45 [INFO] npm WARN codelyzer@5.2.1 requires a peer of tslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
14:49:45 [INFO] npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/fsevents):
14:49:45 [INFO] npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
14:49:45 [INFO] 
14:49:45 [INFO] npm ERR! Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
14:49:45 [INFO] 
14:49:45 [INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Need some help figuring out the fix for the error.

Comment: what node.js version do you use ? node --version

Comment: Running locally v12.13.1, but Jenkins Node: 10.16.3v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with that Node Version [on Windows](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1941), downgrade the Version to 10.15.x (or upgrade to latest) should fix your problem.

don't forget to change the Node Version on Jenkins, go to the Global Tool Configuration on Jenkins and pick the version there.

Comment: Are you talking about Jenkins node version?

Comment: So yeah, that's the problem, you see I can't figure out how to change the version of node in Jenkins, because providing `NODEJS_HOME` and `PATH` to the pipeline configuration doesn't solve the issue, because `No tool named Node 12.x.x found`

Comment: Go to the Global Tool Configuration on Jenkins and pick the version there.

Comment: There is node version configuration in Jenkins configs. I'll try and contact admins to change it somehow. Will let you know if that worked